# Limit and derivates

Tags: limits

I have a question.
Show that, if the limit of a function when it approaches to infinite equals zero, then the limit of the derivative of the same function equals zero.

Thanks

Comment: This is not true. To make it true, we need additional conditions on $f$.

Comment: what is this condition?

Comment: For example, $f$ monotonically decreasing will do it.

Answer (score 2):

consider for example 
$$
f(x) =  \frac 1x\sin (x^2)
$$
We have $|f(x)|\le \frac 1x$, so $f(x) \to_{x\to\infty} 0 $, but
$$
f'(x) =   \frac 1x2x\cos (x^2) - \frac 1{x^2}\sin (x^2) = 2\cos (x^2) + o(1)
$$
has no limit when $x\to\infty$.

Actually, if $f'(x) \to l$, and suppose $l>0$ ($l<0$ is similar) there is an $A$ such as $$
x>A \Rightarrow f'(x) \ge\frac l2\\
x>A \Rightarrow f(x) \ge \frac l2 (x-A) + f(A) \to \infty
$$
Conclusion: if $f(x)\to l_1$ and $f'(x)\to l_2$, then $l_2 = 0$.